# Put all non zero values at the right of an array

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

I have an fixed size array of n elements containing integers. I want to put all the non zero values at the right side of the array.

Examples:

```
[1, 0, 0, 4] => [0, 0, 1, 4]
[2, 0, 4, 3] => [0, 2, 4, 3]
[1, 0, 0] => [0, 0, 1]
```

What would be a simple algorithm to perform this?

This is what I currently have but it only shifts the element at index to right

```
def slide(arr):

    i = len(arr) - 2
    while i >= 0:

        if arr[i] != 0 and arr[i + 1] == 0:
            arr[i + 1] = arr[i]
            arr[i] = 0

        i -= 1

    print(arr)
```

Comment: Do you need to preserve the relative order of elements?

Comment: @sebastian yes it is very important that I keep the order of the elements

Comment: Do you also have time and space complexity requirements?

Comment: @JMLontoc I actually meant you should add your code into the question with an edit. Make sure to follow the guide [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @sebastian I do not have requirements but I think it is best to have a straightforward and intuitive approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would count the zeros, remove them and include them at the beginning:

```
zeros = [0] * arr.count(0)
while 0 in arr:
    arr.remove(0)
arr = zeros + arr
```

Comment: Nice approach! Didn't think of this one. Thanks!

Comment: Beware of large lists :)  (algorithm is quadratic)

Comment: @MBo True, I didn't think much about runtime-complexity here

Comment: @Aemyl Author did not ask about effectiveness, so all simple and working solutions are good.

Answer (score 2):

To shift values right with their initial order:
(inplace, linear time complexity)

```
def slide(arr):
    zeros = 0
    for i in range(len(arr) - 1, -1, -1):
        if arr[i] == 0:
            zeros += 1
        else:
            arr[i+zeros] = arr[i]
    for i in range(zeros):
        arr[i] = 0
    print(arr)

slide([1,0,2,0,0,3])

>>[0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I do like this one. Clever!

Answer (score 1):

```
Create a new array, same size, initialized with 0's.

Scan the first array:
    if the current element is not zero:
        copy it into the second array starting from the end
```

Time complexity: O(n)
Space complexity: O(n)

> straightforward and intuitive approach